# Why can't I connect to MQTT with mosquitto_sub 1.14.15 but can with 2.0.11

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to connect to a MQTT broker on an older version of `mosquitto_sub` v1.14.15 with the command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h <host_url> -p 8883 -t '#' -u <username> -P <pw> -d -i <myidentity>
```

from the command I get the output of:

```
Client myidentity sending CONNECT
Error: Unrecognised command 16

Error: A network protocol error occurred when communicating with the broker.
```

however with the same command I can connect on `mosquitto_sub` version 2.0.11. The intial connection details show as:

```
Client myidentity sending CONNECT
Client myidentity received CONNACK (0)
Client myidentity sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: #, QoS: 0, Options: 0x00)
Client myidentity received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0`
```

Anyone know what could be causing the issue on the older version or how to debug or if there could be options on the broker that could enable the older version to work?

Comment: What broker are you connecting to (and does it log anything). Please confirm the version of `mosquitto_sub` (there was a version `1.4.15` but I don't think v1 went past `1.6.12`). If you are dealing with `1.4.15` then that defaulted to MQTT v3.1 which may be an issue; try `-V mqttv311`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the system I'm having issue with is on `mosquitto_sub version 1.4.15 running on libmosquitto 1.4.15` I've tried with the `-V mqttv311` and get the same `Unrecognised command 16` error . I'm waiting to hear back on server logs from the broker.

Answer (score 0):

mosquitto_sub version 1.4.15 was sending the connect unencrytped (verified with wireshark). I modified the command to add `--capath` option and it works.

`mosquitto_sub -h <host_url> -p 8883 -t '#' -u <username> -P <pw> -d -i <myidentity> --capath /etc/ssl/certs/`

mosquitto_sub 2.0.11 doesn't require this option.